# Cross domain uploading for jQuery File Upload

Tags: php, jquery, upload, cross-domain

I know this has been asked on SO before, but everything I've tried doesn't seem to work...I'm using [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) by BlueImp, and I need to do a cross-domain upload (from admin.cookingwiththecooks.net to wwwdev.cookingwiththecooks.net)

I've looked at how to do it, and here's my headers for `index.php` (on the receiving server)

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
```

Looks right to me...

When I go to upload the file, I get this error:

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://wwwdev.cookingwiththecooks.net/. Origin http://admin.cookingwiththecooks.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

So apparently something's wrong with the headers.  Can anyone help me with this?  Let me know if more info is needed...

BTW the upload folder does have write permissions.  Thanks!

EDIT:  I'm now looking at the possibility of using an iframe for this...

Here's my Javascript code, can you make sure I'm doing this correctly?

```
$('#new-recipe-form').fileupload({
    forceIframeTransport: true,
    url: 'http://wwwdev.cookingwiththecooks.net/',
    disableImageResize: false,
    dropZone: $('#dropzone'),
    imageMaxWidth: 1800,
    imageMaxHeight: 1800,
});

$('#new-recipe-form').fileupload(
    'option',
    'redirect',
    'http://admin.cookingwiththecooks.net/recipes/result.html?%s'
);
```

I did create the `result.html`, and from what I understand it's supposed to be blank...?

Here's the link I used: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Cross-domain-uploads#cross-site-iframe-transport-uploads

Thanks again!

Comment: Any chance of getting the real URL?

Comment: The best way in my opinion would be to simply submit the form to a hidden iframe targeting the subdomain.

Comment: Also, you could even make receiving response data easy using postmessages. Here's a short tutorial: http://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe

Comment: @KevinB now I get the error "Empty file upload result".  Just to be clear, here's the link I saw about using iframes. https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Cross-domain-uploads#cross-site-iframe-transport-uploads

Comment: @KevinB see my updated code above...

Comment: I don't know, i've never used the fileupload plugin. Not quite sure what it does. I've always just rolled my own.

Comment: @KevinB well then do you have any answers for solving my original question?  I'd rather just stick with the plugin, but I have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Comment: The headers look fine to me.

Comment: By the way, empty file upload result. I'm betting that's because you aren't handling the redirect url parameter correctly, as described at the link you provided last. *"On server-side, you need to check if a request parameter redirect has been transmitted with the file upload. In this case, the server response to the upload has to be a redirect to this parameter, with..."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't get a solution, so I just used FTP to upload it to another domain...